# SQL Server: what is the virtual log file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, transaction-log

What is the Virtual Transaction Log file in SQL Server?

Comment: a transaction log file is made up from several small virtual log files and the goal is to manage the small number of the virtual log files in the transaction log file, because SQL Server handles the smaller number of files easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179355.aspx):

> The SQL Server Database Engine divides
>   each physical log file internally into
>   a number of virtual log files. Virtual
>   log files have no fixed size, and
>   there is no fixed number of virtual
>   log files for a physical log file. The
>   Database Engine chooses the size of
>   the virtual log files dynamically
>   while it is creating or extending log
>   files. The Database Engine tries to
>   maintain a small number of virtual
>   files. The size of the virtual files
>   after a log file has been extended is
>   the sum of the size of the existing
>   log and the size of the new file
>   increment. The size or number of
>   virtual log files cannot be configured
>   or set by administrators.

---

> The transaction log is a wrap-around
>   file. For example, consider a database
>   with one physical log file divided
>   into four virtual log files. When the
>   database is created, the logical log
>   file begins at the start of the
>   physical log file. New log records are
>   added at the end of the logical log
>   and expand toward the end of the
>   physical log. Log truncation frees any
>   virtual logs whose records all appear
>   in front of the minimum recovery log
>   sequence number (MinLSN).

[image]

> When the end of the logical log
>   reaches the end of the physical log
>   file, the new log records wrap around
>   to the start of the physical log file.

[image]